# C++ "vector iterator not dereferencable" in runtime

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, dereference

implementing this simple program I found out, in runtime, an error that occurs when i type the eof at the end of the **FIRST** while. The error says "*vector iterator not dereferencable*". Is that possible? The iterators are declared after the while cycles! I still cannot understand what i misspelled. Can someone help me?
Ps. The program should check if a vector is a prefix for the other. Thank you! Here's the main function:

```
   int main(){
        vector<int> v1, v2;
        cout << "1st vector: enter integers" << endl;
        int i, j;
        while (cin >> i){
            v1.push_back(i);
        }
        cout << "2nd vector: enter integers" << endl;
        while (cin >> j){
            v2.push_back(j);
        }
        vector<int>::const_iterator i1 = v1.begin();
        vector<int>::const_iterator i2 = v2.begin();
        while ((*i1) && (*i2) && ((*i1) == (*i2))){
            ++i1; ++i2;
        }
        if ((*i1) && (*i2))
            cout << "Vectors not compatible." << endl;
        else
        if (!(*i1))
            cout << "The 1st vector is a prefix for the 2nd." << endl;
        else
            cout << "The 2nd vector is a prefix for the 1st." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`vector<int>` is not a null-terminated c-style string. So to check whether an iterator reached the end, you need to compare it with the end iterator. So instead of `(*i1) && (*i2)` you should write `(i1 != v1.end()) && (i2 != v2.end())` in both cases. Same goes for `!(*i1)`. You should change it to `i1 == v1.end()`.

@RSahu describes the first problem you hit. You will hit the problem that I described once you fix the first one.

To fix the problem he described, you should clear the bad bits and ignore whatever is left in `cin`'s buffer. Add the following lines before your second `while` loop:

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore();
```

[LIVE](http://cpp.sh/8xqqg)

Comment: I've already tried to do exactly what you say, but it still doesn't work!

Comment: @GiovanniPrestigiacomo see my edit and R Sahu's answer.

Comment: @GiovanniPrestigiacomo added some more info

Comment: @GiovanniPrestigiacomo Feel free to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the first eof on `cin`, it stays there. The second while loop effectively becomes a noop, since `cin` thinks it's done. From there, we run through:

```
vector<int>::const_iterator i1 = v1.begin();
vector<int>::const_iterator i2 = v2.begin();
while ((*i1) && (*i2) && ((*i1) == (*i2))){
                 ^^^
                 UB!
```

And you're dereferencing `i2` without checking `v2`'s size.

First, you have to clear `std::cin`:

```
std::cin.clear();
```

And then, the right way to check if you're done with a vector is to compare the iterator to `end()` (as opposed to simply dereferencing):

```
while (i1 < v1.end() && i2 < v2.end() && *i1 == *i2) {
    ++i1;
    ++i2;
}
```

Though if you have access to a C++14 compiler, you could simply use [`std::mismatch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch):

```
auto res = std::mismatch(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
if (res.first < v1.end()) {
    if (res.second < v2.end()) {
        std::cout << "Not compatible!" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "The 2nd vector is a prefix for the 1st." << std::endl;
    }
}
else {
    std::cout << "The 1st vector is a prefix for the 2nd." << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following block:

```
    while (cin >> i){
        v1.push_back(i);
    }
```

makes sure that `cin >> j` fails. Hence, nothing gets added to `v2` in the block:

```
    while (cin >> j){
        v2.push_back(j);
    }
```

Since `v2` is empty, using `*i2` leads to undefined behavior.